# ALSA device not found by PyAudio

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, microphone, alsa, pyaudio

On my Raspberry Pi I added an audio device to ALSA by adding the following to `~/.asoundrc`:

```
pcm_slave.usb16 {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
    format S16_LE
    channels 1
}

pcm.rate_convert {
    type plug
    slave usb16
}
```

When calling `arecord -L` the device `rate_convert` is listed but when listing all devices in PyAudio this device is not listed. Why is this? And how can I use this device in python?

Comment: Can you share the code you're using with PyAudio to list devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code to find device and their index

```
import pyaudio

po = pyaudio.PyAudio()
for index in range(po.get_device_count()): 
    desc = po.get_device_info_by_index(index)
    print ("DEVICE: {0} \t INDEX: {1} \t RATE: {2}".format(desc["name"],index,int(desc["defaultSampleRate"])))
```